# How to verify a DB migration with a query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

Using Postgres, SQL Developer and dBeaver.

I need to verify a data migration by scanning a series of columns (36 to be exact) to ensure two unique values were pulled from the 36 columns.

The rules of the migration are:

- for each prg_id in table, traverse all chan1..36 values in ascending order
- insert chan1 value into schema.prg.vcn1 column
- traverse the remaining CHAN(i.e., chan2, chan3, etc). If another unique CHAN is found, insert it into vcn2 column.
- stop processing this prg_id and continue to the next.

This all happens in the same table (schema.prg). An example of the data is shown below. The latter two columns are the ones that I am seeking to be correctly populated. The example below shows what a successful DB migration ought to look like (I have about 4,500 rows to verify).

| prg_id | chan1 | chan2 | chan3 | ...chan36 | vcn1 | vcn2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5100 | 100 | 100 | 262 | 0 | 100 | 262 |
| 3252 | 43 | 43 | 52 | 52 | 43 | 52 |
| 4272 | 76 | null | null | null | 76 | 0 |

I have attempted to query with CASE statements but can't get it right. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Fix your data model!  Storing values in a row like this is very cumbersome!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the unique ids, in order, using a lateral join:

```
select t.*, c.chans
from t cross join lateral
     (select array_agg(chan order by ord) as chans
      from (select chan, min(ord) as ord
            from (values (1, t.chan1), (2, t.chan2), . . . ) v(ord, chan)
            where chan <> 0
            group by chan
           ) c
     ) c;
```

I'm not sure why you would want a variable number of columns.  The array should do what you want.  You can access elements of the array using array notation:  `chans[1] as vcn1, chans[2] as vcn2, . . .` .